# NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I use HBM mapping.
I have tables :

I) person with columns : 
1. ID
2. TYPE
3.CREATE_DATE
4.UPDATE_DATE

II) Attribute with columns: 
1.ID
2.TYPE(in this example person may be all type)
3.NAME
4.CREATE_DATE
5.UPDATE_DATE

III) Attribute_VALUE with columns: 
1.ID
2.VALUE
4.OBJECT_ID
5.ATTRIBUTE_ID
6.CREATE_DATE
7.UPDATE_DATE

There is relationship one-to-many between person(ID) and Attribute_VALUE(OBJECT_ID).
There is relationship one-to-many between Attribute(ID) and Attribute_VALUE(ATTRIBUTE_ID)
I need build object PERSON that contain all columns of person and dictionary with name attribute. 
The dictionary contain key - name of attribute value- collection of values .

Can I build appropriate HBM ??

Answer (score 0):

the short answer **no**.

the long answer:

consider how should nhibernate match attributes when you `Attributes.Add("foo", "value")`? it has to search the db for an attribute *foo* (which is not a simple mapping, its logic) or it would create a new Attribute, everytime you add one.

So given the above schema you either **a)** have some kind of custom onsave code (which i think is a lot of effort) or **b)** you change the Person to

```
class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AttributeValue> Attributes { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetValues(string attributeName)
    {
        return Attributes
            .Where(attr => attr.Attribute.Name == attributeName)
            .Select(attr => attr.Value);
    }

    public virtual void AddValue(Attribute attribute, string value)
    {
        Attributes.Add(new AttributeValue
        {
            Attribute = attribute,
            Value = value
        });
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<string> GetAttributeNames()
    {
        return Attributes
            .Select(attr => attr.Attribute.Name);
    }
}

class Attribute
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    // and more Properties like created and updated
}

class AttributeValue
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }

    // and more Properties like created and updated
}
```

and then use

```
<class name="Person" table="Persons" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <id name="Id" column="ID"/>
  <bag name="Attributes">
    <key column="OBJECT_ID"/>
    <one-to-many class="AttributeValue"/>
  </bag>
</class>

<class name="Attribute" table="Attributes" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <id name="Id" column="ID"/>
  <property name="Name" column="Name"/>
  <!--additional properties-->
</class>

<class name="AttributeValue" table="AttributeValues" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <id name="Id" column="ID"/>
  <many-to-one class="Attribute" column="ATTRIBUTE_ID"/>
  <property name="Value" column="Value"/>
  <!--additional properties-->
</class>
```