# Fluent NHibernate Mapping issues

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following classes and tables, I want to find out how to map it in Fluent Nhibernate:

```
class File
        {
            public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<FileParameter> FileParameters { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<File> DetailFile { get; set; }
        }

        class FileParameter
        {
            public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual File MasterFile { get; set; }
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

            public virtual FileParameterValue FileParameterValue { get; set; }

        }

        class FileParameterValue
        {
            public virtual int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual File ParentFile { get; set;}
            public virtual FileParameter FileParameter { get; set; }
            public virtual string DefaultValue { get; set; }
            public virtual bool DisplayStatus { get; set; }
        }
```

Databse table

```
Table File
FileId, 

Table FileParameter
ParameterId, FileId, Name, DisplayName

Table FileParameterValue
FileParameterValueId, ParameterId, FileId, DefaultValue, DisplayStatus
```

What I want to achieve is that, there is one master file and its many details files. Each master file has its own FileParameter, and FileParameValue. Each of the master file's child files use the master file's FileParameter, but has its own FileParameterValue.

Any ideal would be very much appreicated.

Comment: Could you clarify the relationship between a Master file and child files? I don't see that in your object / db model.

Comment: @Thilak Nathen Please refer to class File.

Answer (score 0):

```
class File
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IDictionary<FileParameter, FileParameterValue> Parameters { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<File> Details { get; set; }
}

class FileParameter
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual File MasterFile { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

class FileParameterValue
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual File ParentFile { get; set; }
    public virtual FileParameter FileParameter { get; set; }
    public virtual string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public virtual bool DisplayStatus { get; set; }
}

class FileMap : ClassMap<File>
{
    public FileMap()
    {
        Id(file => file.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        HasMany(file => file.Parameters)
            .AsEntityMap("ParameterId");

        // additional Properties
    }
}

class FileParameterMap : ClassMap<FileParameter>
{
    public FileParameterMap()
    {
        Id(param => param.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        References(param => param.MasterFile, "FileId");

        // additional Properties
    }
}

class FileParameterValueMap : ClassMap<FileParameterValue>
{
    public FileParameterValueMap()
    {
        Id(param => param.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        References(param => param.FileParameter, "ParameterId");

        // additional Properties
    }
}
```

you have to make sure programmatically, that if you add a parametervalue in a detailsfile you use a parameter-object of the master file

see also for a similar problem [NHibernate mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835673/nhibernate-mapping/6841778#6841778)